# Remove a tag from a xml using wso2 6.1 Enrich mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have the follow xml structure:

```
<a>
 <b>
   <c>foo</c>
 </b>
 <d>foo</d>
</a>
```

and I need to remove the tag `<b>` from the xml.

So, the xml should be like that, at the end:

```
<a>
  <d>foo</d>
</a>
```

I've tried to use Enrich Mediator, wso2 6.1, but I didn't have success.

Someone could help to figured out how remove this tag?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't easily remove a child element like that with enrich mediator.
If your payload was something like this:

```
<Body>
  <b>
    <c>foo</c>
  </b>
  <d>foo</d>
</Body>
```

It would be a simple matter of selecting the second tag and replacing the body with it:

```
<enrich>
  <source clone="true" xpath="$body/d"/>
  <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
```

But in this case, since you need to remove a child element from `<a>` you might want to use a script mediator to do that:

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
     var message = mc.getPayloadXML();
     delete message.b;
     mc.setPayloadXML(message);
]]></script>
```

Which will get you your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

You can use XSLT mediator.
The XSLT could either be a Local Entry or in the registry.

You can achieve what you want by using an empty template to match what you don't want and copy everything else:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've used XSLT mediator and worked!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve with Script mediator.

[1] http://mrmalakasilva.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-remove-xml-elements-using-script.html

[2] http://sumedhask.blogspot.com/search/label/WSO2%20Enterprise%20Service%20Bus

[3]http://www.vitharana.org/2016/02/wso2-esb-how-to-remove-jsonobject-root.html

Comment: Consider writing down the answer or solution instead of a collection of links. A. the links only provide an indirect answer. B. the links might suffer from Linkrot eventually and make the answer useless/incomplete.  Links that support your anwser are fine by the way.